# Can an __init__ function in a class be added to or altered without overwriting it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, setattr

In Python 3.x with the given class hierarchy, where `SubClassZero` and `SubClassOne` inherit from `SuperClass`;

```py
class SuperClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.thing_zero = "Inherited string."

class SubClassZero(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        SuperClass.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.thing_one = "SubClassZero's string."

class SubClassOne(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        SuperClass.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.thing_one = "SubClassOne's string."

scz = SubClassZero()
sco = SubClassOne()
```

If we want to give the subclasses the ability set a title from a `kwarg` then the `__init__` function of SuperClass can be redefined using the the built `setattr` function like so;

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.thing_zero = "Inherited string."
    if 'title' in kwargs:
        self.title = kwargs['title']
    else:
        self.title = ""

setattr(SuperClass, '__init__', __init__)
```

But to do that one has to know the previous structure of `__init__` to maintain full functionality. Is there a way to somehow add to the `__init__` function of `SuperClass` without completely overwriting it?

Comment: Why are you trying to change `SuperClass.__init__`? Why aren't the subclass constructors handling this?

Comment: That's a good point. I'm trying force all of the subclasses of a popular module to inherit the same behavior without having to essentially rewrite the init for superclass.

Comment: Then put another class between `SuperClass` and the derived classes, with the behavior you want.

Comment: Thank you @AryaMcCarthy. Yes that would work, but I would like avoid altering the subclasses. I'm trying to alter all of the subclasses of superclass for a python module without having to change the source code.